# Get all committed data from svn for today

Tags: svn

I need to get a list of authors who have made changes to the SVN today and changed data of revision. When I use "svn blame [FILE]" or "svn annotate [FILE]". I only get the information about latest revision of the author. How can I get information on all the revisions for today?

"svn log [FILE]" don't work for me, because I need to parse returned svn data

Comment: And how difficult is it to parse svn log?

Comment: If you want an easier time parsing in applications, just use `svn log --xml FILE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Windows you can use PowerShell to easily generate Subversion reports of this type. I wrote a small suite of tools to analyze Subversion meta-data of the sort you are looking for. Here is one example to report the information you are asking for:

```
Get-SvnLog -ByFile |
select Revision,Author,Date,Path |
? { $_.Date -ge (Get-Date((Get-Date).AddDays(-1))) } |
sort -property @{ e="Path"; Descending=$false }, @{ e="Revision"; Descending=$true } |
Format-Table -AutoSize
```

You can see the API for Get-SvnLog in my [open source bookshelf](http://cleancode.sourceforge.net/wwwdoc/APIbookshelf.html). Open the PowerShell "book" and go to SvnTools. Download the code [here](http://cleancode.sourceforge.net/wwwdoc/download.html).